# When using iostream in vs2010, I get error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream

This problem has been haunting me for weeks. I am using MS vs2010.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers:" << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " and " << v2
    << " is " << v1 + v2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A simple program from C++ Primer. When I compile it, I get the following error information:

> 1>e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(24): error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>
> 1>e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(24): error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

I was trying to find some solution, and I got this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/Vsexpressvc/thread/31385f37-94b8-4297-b054-7fdbc5b1f51e

which says:

> SOLUTION FOUND:
>
> I have researched this issue on the web and it seems like it is something that has been an issue for a lot of people. The solution to this is as simple as removing a comment.
>
> I looked through the stdlib.h file, and found the the following line was commended out:

```
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl exit(__in int _Code);
```

> I took out the comment and recompiled it, and now it works.
>
> I believe in some builds the stdlib.h file will automatically be compiled with that portion of the code commented out. simple uncomment and your code will work.

Apparently some people fixed the problem with this solution. However, I could not even find `_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl exit(__in int _Code);` in my stdlib.h.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: please put your answer in an answer and accept it yourself. That way, the site works `;-)`.

Comment: @rubenvb I don't know for sure what you are suggesting, but I haven't got a solution yet. The so-called 'solution' I posted in the question works for some people, but it didn't work for me. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: Well, you did shout `SOLUTION FOUND`... but I didn't bother to read any further.

Comment: @rubenvb Well, that's my fault. I should have made it clearer. Someone just edited it for me, it should be ok now.

Comment: Thank you, @Bo Persson, my question is much more organized after you edited it.

Comment: It's a hack but you could try: `#include <cstdlib>` and a `using std::exit;` before you include iostream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I looked through the stdlib.h file, and found the the following line was commended out:

It should **NOT** be commented out.  That part of stdlib.h should look like this:

```
#ifndef _CRT_TERMINATE_DEFINED
#define _CRT_TERMINATE_DEFINED
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl exit(_In_ int _Code);
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl _exit(_In_ int _Code);
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl abort(void);
#endif
```

It isn't clear how it got to be commented in your version of the file.  But it is clear that you don't hesitate to edit compiler header files to get out of a problem.  You may have done this before to bypass a problem and not remember it.

In general, this is a Really Really Bad Idea.  Microsoft releases service packs and security updates that will update compiler header files.  But it will not do so if the file was altered.  Which may leave you with a nasty mixed bag of files that are no longer compatible with each other.

You will need to fix the damage done to these files.  Pay attention to the modified timestamp of these files to find out which might have been changed.  And copy those from a known-good machine of, say, a friend or colleague.  Another possible approach (never tried it myself) is to move the altered files somewhere else and run setup again, asking for a repair.  Not actually sure if that works, it should.  Also re-apply service packs when you do it that way.

Comment: Well, I just reinstalled vs2010, and I don't have that problem anymore. I didn't actually edit header files, I was just following the solution which said he checked the header file. I don't know why I had a weird stdlib.h, but I used to have both vc2010 express and vs2010 installed, I guess that may be the reason. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: No, that's not the reason.  Another opportunity lost to actually truly diagnose this common problem.  Never looked at the timestamps, did you?  So this is likely to happen again.

Comment: No, I didn't look at the timestamps, because I really didn't modify any header files. I installed vs2010 just a few weeks ago, and I have been having this problem since then. I searched it in google, and found a great number of people having this problem as well. As you said, it is a common problem. The only solution I found is the one I posted in my question, which did not work. So, what was I supposed to do except for reinstalling my compiler?