# Error C2039: 'exit' and Error C2873: 'exit' (Suddenly Wont Compile)

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors

I have a C++ and OpenGL/GLSL program that has been running fine all day.

I took a break from programming and watched a movie. Upon coming back to my programming and running it again, it no-longer compiles... Absolutely nothing has changed.

Theses are the errors:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  console.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>  Cube.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>  opengl3template.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>  Shader.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(24): error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Which link to this below in the `cstdlib`:

```
using _CSTD exit;
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I have literally just rebooted my computer and recompiled the code... Still the same problem... The `cstdlib` is a read only file too... So strange; apart from watching a film, nothing has been done on the machine since I run the program a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

For some reason in the `stdlib.h` header the following line of code was commented out:

```
_CRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl exit(_In_ int _Code);
```

I only checked the header because it was mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014348/when-using-iostream-in-vs2010-i-get-error-c2039-exit-is-not-a-member-of?rq=1) post.

I'm not sure why or why it's only affected the compiler now, but un-commenting it has resolved the problem and the program executed fine.